# MySQL - Copy Initialized Data Folder to another PC

Tags: mysql

MySQL server 5.7, after 1st deploy, the data folder is required to be initialized once before the 1st use.

It is ok to copy the initialized data folder to another pc? Will it stable to be used?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Make sure to shut down the mysql processes first. You should also not "downgrade" by this, so the destination server should be at least the same version than your existing server.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for the info. by the way, if the server is not being shutdown properly, something wrong might happened right? even in the situation of sudden power off?

Comment: If the server is not shut down properly, both servers will (try to) repair what they can when you restart them. This might (but does not have to) fail if your versions do not match. With a properly shut down server, you can "upgrade" this way, which you should not do otherwise (although it will probably work). Also, I forgot to mention, if your second server has a conflicting configuration, it might give you unexpected results (but so would changing the configuration of the first server to the same values), so you might want to check the error log after the first start for some warnings.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for the info. you may repost as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Make sure to shut down the mysql processes first. You should also not "downgrade" by this, so the destination server should be at least the same version than your existing server. by @Solarflare

Comment: You also should then run a "repair table" on each table you copied